# The best way to store styling values in JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, architecture

IMGUR: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiSQs.jpg

Hi all,
Supposed we have an editor's screen like the one we have here at Stackoverflow to draft a question. Once we click submit, the backend is supposed to call method to generate a JSON. My questions are:

1. How are the JSON values stored? If I have a post and I want to change the `color` or `font size` of a text, for example, the word `JSON` in this string `JSON (JavaScript Object Notation, pronounced /ˈdʒeɪsən/; also /ˈdʒeɪˌsɒn/) is an open standard file format, and data interchange format, that uses human-readable text to store and transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs and array data types (or any other serializable value)` without affecting the rest of the string, would the correct schema be like below:

```
{
    "title": title,
    content: [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "<style="color:red">JSON</style> (JavaScript Object Notation, pronounced /ˈdʒeɪsən/; also /ˈdʒeɪˌsɒn/) is an open standard file format, and data interchange format, that uses human-readable text to store and transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs and array data types (or any other serializable value)."
        },
        {
            "type": "image",
            "value": "imageId"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. If I did the schema like above, once I get back the JSON from the client, I foresee a problem with going through the whole string and parse out the necessary styles. Therefore I don't think my above schema is optimized. What are some of the best ways to approach this scenario?
3. The flow of the JSON generation: Usually, upon clicking "Publish", does this editor send a POST request to the server, which in turn generates the JSON? If yes, then what is included in that POST request?

Answer (score 0):

**1**:

well yes the approach is pretty good in my opinion for the following reason

- if you are using a `contenteditable` div then you can directly set the `innerHTML` via JavaScript without any parsing.....or you can use the id(s) to custom style it.

**2**:

It's not bad of a approach as everything is easy to manage.

**3**:

I don't know about the draft requests but on submit it does or it must send a post request.

The post request might be done using `fetch()` like....

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
// if your api sends a confirmation response

//.then(response => response.json())
//.then(data => {
//  console.log('Success:', data);
//})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```